Compute the integral $\int_{\gamma }ze^{z^{2}}dz$
I was asked to calculate $\int_{\gamma }ze^{z^{2}}dz$, where
(a) $\gamma$ is a line segment from $i$ to $2-i$.
(b) $\gamma$ is a part of parabola $y=x^2$ from $0$ to $1+i$.
I know I should find the parametrization form of the curve $\gamma$, and calculate. But I try to solve it by another way as follows:
Since the function $f(z)=ze^{z^{2}}$ is defined and continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, and has the antiderivative $F(z)=\frac{1}{2}e^{z^{2}}$, then the integral is independent of the curve $\gamma$, only dependent on the starting point and ending point. Thus,
(a) $\int_{\gamma }ze^{z^{2}}dz=\int_{i}^{2-i}ze^{z^{2}}dz=\frac{1}{2}e^{z^{2}}|^{2-i}_{i}=\frac{1}{2}\left ( e^{(2-i)^{2}}-e^{i^{2}} \right )=\frac{1}{2}\left ( e^{3-4i}-e^{-1} \right )$
(b) similarly
Is this way correct? Do I need to prove the above arguments before calculating? Do I need to add anything else to improve it? Thanks!

It looks fine to me. But it may that your teacher wants you to follow the parameterization approach so that you can see the path independence for yourself.
